# How to create editable elements in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, slider

I want to use in cakephp app a content slider (like this http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/). Content of this element can be changed in admin panel. 
I just want to put some code in layout view to insert the element on website. How to create the element like this? It should be Helper, Plugin or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Think of the element as a view. Set a variable in the controller (depending on admin options, which are stored in a database, probably) using `$this->set('myvar', $data);` and access the variables in the view as you would normally:

**Somewhere in yourview.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->element('contentslider'); ?>
```

**View/Elements/contentslider.ctp**

```
<?php 
/* print all images in the set array */
foreach($myvar['images'] as $image){
echo $image['url'];
}
/* print link only if admin is logged in */
if ($myvar['adminloggedin'] == true){
echo $this->Html->link('/admin'/);
}
?>
```

etc. The idea here is that you treat the element just as you would a view. Set variables in your controller, and access them in the element with simple for and if logic to print the dynamic content. So for your image slider, you could make a for loop that is like:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($myvar['images'] as $image){
$i++;?>
<div class="panel" title="Panel <?php echo $i; ?>">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/tempphoto-<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg" alt="temp">
                    <div class="photo-meta-data">
                        Photo Credit: <a href="<?php ehco $image['url']; ?>">Kaustav Bhattacharya</a><br>
                        <span><?php echo $image['description']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gwoo/2007/04/12/creating-reusable-elements-with-requestaction